# How to stop several coroutines running on array of game objects

Tags: unity

In the code below, I am running a coroutine on each element of an array of game objects. How can I stop running the `FadeToForEnemy` coroutine on each game object?

```
    IEnumerator EnemyCycle()    {
    while (isRepeating)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Length; j++) {

            Enemy currentEnemy = enemies [j];
            var _myMaterial = currentEnemy.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
            var _currentFade = StartCoroutine(FadeToForEnemy(_myMaterial, 0f, 1f, currentEnemy.gameObject, false));

        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (hdTime);

        for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Length; j++) {

            Enemy currentEnemy = enemies [j];
            var _myMaterial = currentEnemy.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
            var _currentFade = StartCoroutine(FadeToForEnemy(_myMaterial, 1f, 1f, currentEnemy.gameObject, true));

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (srTime);

        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried stopping the coroutines in the following but the cycle of fading in and out just continued.

```
public void StopEnemyCycles ()  {
    for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Length; i++) {
        enemies [i].StopAllCoroutines ();
    }
    StopCoroutine ("EnemyCycle");

}
```

Also below is `FadeToForEnemy`:

```
    IEnumerator FadeToForEnemy(Material material, float targetOpacity, float duration, GameObject gameObj, bool isEnabled) {

    // Cache the current color of the material, and its initiql opacity.
    Color color = material.color;
    float startOpacity = color.a;

    // Track how many seconds we've been fading.
    float t = 0;
    if (isEnabled) {
        gameObj.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ().enabled = isEnabled;

    }

    while(t < duration) {
        // Step the fade forward one frame.
        t += Time.deltaTime;
        // Turn the time into an interpolation factor between 0 and 1.
        float blend = Mathf.Clamp01(t / duration);

        // Blend to the corresponding opacity between start & target.
        color.a = Mathf.Lerp(startOpacity, targetOpacity, blend);

        // Apply the resulting color to the material.
        material.color = color;

        // Wait one frame, and repeat.
        yield return null;

    }

    if (!isEnabled) {
        gameObj.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ().enabled = isEnabled;

    }
}
```

I have several groups of enemies, each group fades in and out at the same time.

Comment: Presumably you've investigated StopCoroutine and StopAllCoroutines? If you had any trouble implementing the behaviour you want with those, can you explain what went wrong/ what kind of help you need? Also, if you're always fading all of your enemies in sync, you might not need to run this coroutine for each enemy - fading a single shared material instance will often be more efficient. We'd need to see more details of your fade routine and what gameplay this is serving to know if that would be appropriate for your case though.

Comment: @DMGregory I just updated the post

Comment: @DMGregory I haven't delved into shaders yet, still trying to grasp a few other stuff, but if using shaders would make things more efficient, I guess this would be the best time to start implementing them :). So is it possible to write a shader that would enable and disable `BoxColliders`?

Comment: @DMGregory how would a shader work in my case?

Comment: You could use it to vary material properties over time, so you don't have to set new material copies on every object. Shaders can't impact the gameplay simulation though, so you'd still need to manage your colliders separately.

Comment: @DMGregory I would be more than grateful if you could possibly show me an example of how this would work

Comment: @DMGregory I would be really appreciate if you could take a look at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/145094/how-to-run-a-timer-parallel-to-a-series-of-coroutines-and-waitforseconds for me. Still trying to get it solved.

Answer (score 1):

you need to go nuclear and do

```
StopAllCoroutines();
```

or save the coroutines that you're starting.

```
var all_coroutines = new List<IEnumerator>();
for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Length; j++) {
        Enemy currentEnemy = enemies [j];
        var _myMaterial = currentEnemy.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        var fade_coroutine = FadeToForEnemy(_myMaterial, 1f, 1f, currentEnemy.gameObject, true);
        all_coroutines.Add(fade_coroutine);
        var _currentFade = StartCoroutine(fade_coroutine );
}
..
foreach(IEnumerator coroutine in all_coroutines) {
    StopCoroutine(coroutine);
}
```

Comment: I saved the list as you did above and run `StopCoroutine`, but the game objects are still fading in and out. Also `all_coroutines` gets populated every time an enemy fades in and out. That means the array might end up growing very large, depending on the number of my enemies, the cycle and the frequency at which I stop the coroutine

Comment: `StopAllCoroutines();` works. But I am at the early stages of game dev and would most definitely be adding some more coroutines. So `StopAllCoroutines();` would stop coroutines I want to continue running