# How to run a timer parallel to a series of coroutines and WaitForSeconds

Tags: unity

In the code below, I have a cycle for enemies appearing and disappearing.

```
IEnumerator EnemyCycle()    {
while (isRepeating)
{

for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Length; j++) {

    canStartUpdatingReset = true;
    Enemy currentEnemy = enemies [j];
    var _myMaterial = currentEnemy.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    var _currentFade = StartCoroutine(FadeToForEnemy(_myMaterial, 0f, fTime, currentEnemy.gameObject, false));

coroutinesToStop.Add(_currentFade);

if (currentEnemy.hasWeapon) {
                weaponCycleCoroutines.Add(StartCoroutine(FadeToForWeapon(currentEnemy.weapon.GetComponent<Renderer>().material, 0f, fadeTime, currentEnemy.weapon, false)));

            }
}

yield return new WaitForSeconds (hideTime);

for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Length; j++) {

    Enemy currentEnemy = enemies [j];
    var _myMaterial = currentEnemy.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    var _currentFade = StartCoroutine(FadeToForEnemy(_myMaterial, 1f, fTime, currentEnemy.gameObject, true));

     coroutinesToStop.Add(_currentFade);
if (currentEnemy.hasWeapon) {
weaponCycleCoroutines.Add(StartCoroutine(FadeToForWeapon(currentEnemy.weapon.GetComponent<Renderer>().material, 1f, fadeTime, currentEnemy.weapon, true)));
}
yield return new WaitForSeconds (showTime);

        }
    }
}
```

I have an `enemyCycleDuration` `float` which is

```
enemyCycleDuration = 60*(hideTime + fadeTime + showTime + fadeTime)
```

Note that `fadeTime` comes from `FadeToForWeapon` and `FadeToForEnemy`. The idea here is I want the `enemyCycleDuration` to be run in parallel to `EnemyCycle()` so it is reset (please see code below) at the same time that

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds (showTime);
```

is reached in the  `EnemyCycle()`.

I am resetting `enemyCycleDuration` in the following way in the `update` method but  `EnemyCycle()` seems to be ahead of `enemyCycleDuration`, always completing before `enemyCycleDuration` is reset. How can I get both to run parallel to each other in timing and complete at the same time?

```
if (canStartUpdatingReset)  {
timeElapsed +=1;
if(timeElapsed >= enemyCycleDuration) {

    timeElapsed = 0;

    Debug.Log ("Reset CycleDuration");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can someone please help me

Answer (score 1):

What is the variable "hideTime"? I don't see where the value of it is being determined.

If I'm understanding your code correctly; coroutines are started/stopped in "EnemyCycle()" here:

```
while (isRepeating)
{

for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Length; j++) {

    canStartUpdatingReset = true;
    Enemy currentEnemy = enemies [j];
    var _myMaterial = currentEnemy.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    var _currentFade = StartCoroutine(FadeToForEnemy(_myMaterial, 0f, fTime, currentEnemy.gameObject, false));

coroutinesToStop.Add(_currentFade);

if (currentEnemy.hasWeapon) {
                weaponCycleCoroutines.Add(StartCoroutine(FadeToForWeapon(currentEnemy.weapon.GetComponent<Renderer>().material, 0f, fadeTime, currentEnemy.weapon, false)));

            }
}
```

What determines the value of this "isRepeating" loop? It looks like the routines started and stopped while nothing is delaying the loop. That leaves the two timers

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds (hideTime);
```

and

```
 yield return new WaitForSeconds (showTime);
```

These two, combined being the total time the cycle will run.
Then you have the cycle duration variable which is 60 * those two timers and the additional values:

```
enemyCycleDuration = 60*(hideTime + fadeTime + showTime + fadeTime)
```

It's very possible I'm misunderstanding your code, which if I am, please let me know where I went wrong. But it looks like the time for the other cycle, EnemyCycleDuration will always be drastically higher then the EnemyCycle() routine.

You might try the "[WaitWhile"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitWhile.html) yield statement in place of "WaitForSeconds", then you can simply tell it to wait until "EnemyCycleDuration" meets the the desired value like this:

```
yield return new WaitWhile (() => EnemyCycleDuration >= [some duration here]);
```

If you want it the other way around, you can change how EnemyCycleDuration is calculated that way your "CanStartUpdating" loop completes sooner.

Comment: I went to "Unanswered" and didn't see the date on this. 
I'm assuming it's probably already solved since 3 years ago lol. 

Either way, maybe this helps someone. I'm also not sure if there is anything against post necromancy here, I couldn't find any rules related to it